# while trying to run program on avd its showing error in AVD

Tags: android, html

I am trying to run my html application using eclipse AVD but its showing warning like

```
WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Vidhi\.android\avd\ruchi.avd/sdcard.img
 ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Users\Vidhi\.android\avd\ruchi.avd/snapshots.img
```

I am not understanding why its not running.Can you give me the solution for this problem?

My .android file is in C drive but my apps are stored in D drive.what to do to solve this problem?

Comment: When loading the AVD, removed tick mark from "Save to Snapshot" and then load it.

Comment: u opened more than one AVD?

Answer (score 1):

I always have same error. Close `Emulator` then delete it and create new and run your app. Its work.